# Distinction between "Clip" and "Intersection" tool in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, clip, intersection, open-source-gis

For a project in marine biology we need to calculate the amount of seabed that is protected by official protected areas for each seabed habitat type. To that end, we clipped a seabed habitat layer with an MPA layer. 
 However, due to the complexity of the layers, clipping takes forever. 
 
 For some apparent reason the "Intersection" tool is a lot faster. Since it generates the same output for our example, using clipping is kind of stupid. 
We have no idea, however, why "Intersection" runs faster than "Clip". Should this not be based on the same algorithms? Why would you ever use "Clip" if you can use "Intersection" with deselecting all attributes from the mask layer? 
 I have taken a look at the source code of QGIS and I think I located the difference between "Clip" and "Intersection":

```
   QgsGeometry newGeometry;
   if ( !engine->contains( inputFeature.geometry().constGet() ) )
      {
        const QgsGeometry currentGeometry = inputFeature.geometry();
        newGeometry = combinedClipGeom.intersection( currentGeometry );
        if ( newGeometry.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes::Unknown || QgsWkbTypes::flatType( newGeometry.wkbType() ) == QgsWkbTypes::GeometryCollection )
        {
          const QgsGeometry intCom = inputFeature.geometry().combine( newGeometry );
          const QgsGeometry intSym = inputFeature.geometry().symDifference( newGeometry );
          newGeometry = intCom.difference( intSym );
        }
      }
```

This code ([qgsalgorithmclip.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/analysis/processing/qgsalgorithmclip.cpp); line 196) is completely missing in "Intersection". I can imagine the *combine()*, *symDifference()* and *difference()* functions eat a lot of run time. What are they doing here exactly and why is this not in "Intersection"? Does this create the distinction between "Clip" and "Intersection"? Does this create the run time difference, as well?

Comment: Hi! Does your mask layer have adjacent geometries on separate features?

Comment: If you ask whether a Marine Protected Area can cover both sand habitat and rock habitat, then yes, the mask layer can have adjacent geometries on separate features (of the input layer). Otherwise you will have to explain your question.

Comment: The clip tool will try to combine all geometries of the MPA layer, to create just one feature with a multipart geometry, and then perform the intersection from one mask (multipart geometry) feature against each feature of the input layer. Outputs for both algorithms are not the same. And in some cases the combine process of the mask layer might create invalid geometries and that could explain the time taken.